# Style file is altering my citation key

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

I need to have a citation inside a chapter title like such:

```
\chapter{blah blah \cite{key}}
```

The style file that I have for following university formatting guides (found [here](https://staff.washington.edu/fox/tex/uwthesis.shtml)) capitalizes titles and consequently the aux file ends up containing the line

```
\citation{KEY}
```

with KEY in all caps.  This causes bibtex to throw an error because I've used the lowercase version elsewhere.

This can easily be fixed by just changing all the citations for that key to all caps, but that's unsatisfying.  **Does anyone know how to protect the case of a citation key inside a chapter title?**

**Edit:** Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass [11pt, proquest] {uwthesis}[2014/11/13]
\begin{document}
\textpages

\chapter{Blah \cite{key}}
\cite{key}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{key}
Author.
\newblock Title.
\newblock {\em Journal}, Numbers.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @cfr: You'll need the uwthesis file from the link above, but I've now included a MWE.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\MakeLowercase{\cite{key}}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass [11pt, proquest] {uwthesis}[2014/11/13]


\begin{document}
\textpages

\chapter{Blah \MakeLowercase{\cite{key}}}
\cite{key}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{key}
Author.
\newblock Title.
\newblock {\emph{Journal}}, Numbers.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

BTW: Use `\emph{...}` instead of the deprecated `{\em ...}`

Comment: This works if they key is all lowercase, what if I want it to be `Key` instead?